# hector slam on ARM

Tags: robotic-arm, slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

first of all let me say that all launch files I post here work on my PC, but not on pandaboard or parallella with Ubuntuarm Ros-hydro.
I tried different launch files but my basic one is the following:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"name="base_to_laser_broadcaster4"     
      args="0.0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_footprint/base_link 1" />                    
<node pkg="tf type="static_transform_publisher"name="base_to_laser_broadcaster3"    
      args="0.0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link/laser_link 1" />                   
<arg name="geotiff_map_file_path" default="$(find hector_geotiff)/maps"/>         
<include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch"/>                     
<include file="$(find hector_geotiff)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch">          
      <arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame"/>   
      <arg name="map_file_path" value="$(arg geotiff_map_file_path)"/>
</include>
```

Even with this one I get

```
[ERROR] [1414485362.668347630]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: "map"     passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

rqt_wtf gives me:

```
 Errors connecting to the following services: * service [/hector_geotiff_node/get_loggers] appears to be                 malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/hector_geotiff_node/get_loggers],       address [  rosrpc://localhost:46397] * service [/hector_geotiff_node/set_logger_level] appears   to  be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/hector_geotiff_node/set_logger_level],    address               [rosrpc://localhost:46397]
```

but I can't make sense from it. Ideas what I'm missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196125/hector-slam-on-arm/) by [Pilif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20606/pilif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-28**:
Please format your launch file so that it is readable.

**Comment by [Pilif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20606/pilif/) on 2014-10-28**:
sorry, should be fixed now

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-28**:
can you share frames.pdf from `rosrun tf view_frames` and `rqt_graph`.

**Comment by [Pilif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20606/pilif/) on 2014-10-29**:
sure - [frames](https://imgur.com/oMiFzVB,tx6AQTr#0) and [graph](https://imgur.com/oMiFzVB,tx6AQTr#1)

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-29**:
Looks like scan matchiing is failed, if scan matching is success hector mapping will broadcast map to scanmatcher_frame. Give a try with [test bag file](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData) .

**Comment by [Pilif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20606/pilif/) on 2014-11-03**:
@bvbdort I tried it - I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect there's a node or nodes that are crashing or running very slowly. I would check the roslaunch output to make sure nothing is crashing, and I would check `top` to see if any of your nodes are using a lot of memory or CPU cycles.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pilif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20606/pilif/) on 2014-10-29**:
No nodes are crashing. In roslaunch there is only the  error about the Trajectory Server. Here is the   [htop](https://imgur.com/C6iVeyk) output. Can, in general, hector_slam be run from a ARMboard ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-29**:
ARM cpus tend to be slower than their x86 counterparts. That said, it looks like you're using all of your CPU cycles. Given that your static transform publishers are using a combined total of 110% of one core, you may want to consider reducing the static transform rate.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-29**:
You may also want to consider switching to the [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) , which uses a single node for publishing transforms and future-dates them, which can prevent transform latency problems.

**Comment by [Pilif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20606/pilif/) on 2014-11-03**:
@ahendrix Thank you will definitely try  robot_state_publisher.